# Create child objects from parent with same property values

Tags: javascript

I have a parent object. I want to create child objects from the parent with the same key value pair.

e.g.

```
parentJSON = {[name:"a1",address:"b1",comp:"c1"],
              [name:"a2",address:"b2",comp:"c1"],
              [name:"a3",address:"b3",comp:"c2"],
              [name:"a4",address:"b4",comp:"c2"],
              [name:"a5",address:"b5",comp:"c2"],
              [name:"a6",address:"b6",comp:"c3"]}
```

Now I want to create child objects having same "comp" value.

e.g.

```
childJSON1 = {[name:"a1",address:"b1",comp:"c1"],
              [name:"a2",address:"b2",comp:"c1"]}

childJSON2 = {[name:"a3",address:"b3",comp:"c2"],
              [name:"a4",address:"b4",comp:"c2"],
              [name:"a5",address:"b5",comp:"c2"]}

childJSON3 = {[name:"a6",address:"b6",comp:"c3"]}
```

This is what I tried to make it little bit (it will change the parent object with a key indicating number of repetition):

```
parentJSON = [1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5];
var i=0, x, count, item;

while(i < parentJSON.length) {
    count = 1;
    item = parentJSON[i];
    x = i+1;

    while(x < parentJSON.length && 
            (x = parentJSON.indexOf(item, x)) != -1) {

        count += 1;
        parentJSON.splice(x,1);
    }

    parentJSON[i] = new Array(parentJSON[i],count);
    ++i;
}

console.log(parentJSON);`
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) What? 2) What is your question?

Comment: so you basically want to group by comp?

Comment: @SayemAhmed - I have updated my question with what I tried...

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all. You are confusing JavaScript object literals (a construct of the JavaScript language syntax) with JSON (a language-independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV). I will edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @FelixKling: that's why its not parsing correctly?

Comment: @Sonali: Among other things, yes.

Comment: @FelixKling - Thanks for editing...I just meant a javaScript object or array..I used JSON thinking if JSON might have some property for acheiving this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all your json is in the incorrect format, it should look like this

```
                   [{name:"a1",address:"b1",comp:"c1"},
                   {name:"a2",address:"b2",comp:"c1"},
                   {name:"a3",address:"b3",comp:"c2"},
                   {name:"a4",address:"b4",comp:"c2"},
                   {name:"a5",address:"b5",comp:"c2"},
                   {name:"a6",address:"b6",comp:"c3"}]
```

An array of objects.

My attempt, also very readable.

```
var result = {};

$.each(parentJSON, function (i, item) {
    if(!result[item.comp]) {
        result[item.comp] = [];
    }

    (result[item.comp]).push(item);
});

alert(JSON.stringify(result))
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQXMP/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all your json is actually invalid. You may have an array of objects, but not object which contains an array like that. Also your arrays looks more like objects, because the syntax with the dots is used for objects. Here is how I guess should look like:

```
var parentJSON = [
    [{name:"a1",address:"b1",comp:"c1"}],
    [{name:"a2",address:"b2",comp:"c1"}],
    [{name:"a3",address:"b3",comp:"c2"}],
    [{name:"a4",address:"b4",comp:"c2"}],
    [{name:"a5",address:"b5",comp:"c2"}],
    [{name:"a6",address:"b6",comp:"c3"}]
];
var child1 = parentJSON.slice(0, 2);
var child2 = parentJSON.slice(2, 5);
```

And you may use the [*.slice*](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) method to get specific elements of the array.

Comment: I am unaware of the values and I don't know how many child objects have repeated data...it should be generic..the parentJSON given in question is an example..

Answer (score 0):

So..you need to clone objects?

maybe tou can try sth like this:

```
var sergi= {
name: "sergi",
age: 33
};

var bill = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sergi)));
bill.name = "Bill";

console.log(sergi);
console.log(bill);
```

Comment: ok, I didn't understand the question...

Answer (score 0):

```
parentJSON = function(){ 
    return [
        {name:"a1",address:"b1",comp:"c1"},
        {name:"a2",address:"b2",comp:"c1"},
        {name:"a3",address:"b3",comp:"c2"},
        {name:"a4",address:"b4",comp:"c2"},
        {name:"a5",address:"b5",comp:"c2"},
        {name:"a6",address:"b6",comp:"c3"}
    ];
}

childJSON1 = new parentJSON().slice(0,2);
childJSON2 = new parentJSON().slice(2,5);
childJSON3 = new parentJSON().slice(5,6);
```

Comment: I am unaware of the values and I don't know how many child objects have repeated data...it should be generic..the parentJSON given in question is an example..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wyNn7/)**

```
var data = [
    [{name:"a1",address:"b1",comp:"c1"}],
    [{name:"a2",address:"b2",comp:"c1"}],
    [{name:"a3",address:"b3",comp:"c2"}],
    [{name:"a4",address:"b4",comp:"c2"}],
    [{name:"a5",address:"b5",comp:"c2"}],
    [{name:"a6",address:"b6",comp:"c3"}]
];


var groups = {};

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    var comp = item.comp;

    delete item.comp;

    if(groups[comp]) {
        groups[comp].push(item);
    } else {
        groups[comp] = [item];
    }
});

var result = $.map(data, function(group, key) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = group;

    return obj;
});
alert(JSON.stringify(groups))
```

Comment: I am not getting it...